# Is it possible to hide extra information at the Nokia maps control from the Windows Phone 8 SDK?

Tags: dictionary, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing Windows Phone 8 app and trying to hide transport icons from the maps as it is not nessesary information at the app:

https://db.tt/DtDAAY9w

I tried both modifiers disabled but it didn't help:

- LandmarksEnabled="False"
- PedestrianFeaturesEnabled="False"

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: It seems like this is not possible. The properties you mentioned are described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Pedestrianfeaturesandlandmarks Unfortunately there are no other ways to change the layout accordingly.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately those are not implemented with the API. They are actually added there as a layer, and those items could also have interaction. At least the HERE Maps (Same data in the end) with Nokia X does have this functionality implemented and working